# CSS Rendered Differently for FF and IE8

Tags: php, html, css, cross-browser

Below I have included some HTML/CSS. The CSS looks fine in FF, but it is wrong in IE8. In IE8, the Home button appears on the line below the Balance and Turn values. It should appear on the same line. For comparison, you can view the page in both browsers [(warning; potentially accesses FB profile)](http://apps.facebook.com/rails_across_europe) (This link leads to a Facebook app which will request your profile. You have to start a new game, choose a difficulty level, and then you will be taken to the game board. The code in question is at the bottom of the page). I hope someone can tell me how to fix the CSS for IE8. Thanks.

HTML CODE:

```
$html .= '<div id="info-panel">'."\n";
$html .= '  <div id="total-funds">Balance: &euro;<span id="total-amount">'.$gamePlayerData['funds'].'</span>M</div>'."\n";
$html .= '  <div id="turn">Turn: '.$newTurn.'</div>'."\n";
$html .= '  <div id="home"><a href="'  . $config->url->absolute->fb->canvas . '/"><img src="' . $config->url->absolute->public . '/images/home_24x24.png" id="img-home" alt="Home" /></a></div>'."\n";
$html .= '</div>'."\n";
```

CSS CODE:

```
  #info-panel {
    width: 742px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: red;
    padding: 6px;
  }

  #total-funds {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  #turn {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  div#home {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
  }

  #img-home {
    margin-top: -3px;
  }
```

Comment: No, I will not give you access to my Facebook profile. If you want to provide a live test case (which is a good idea), then let's have one that doesn't have strings attached.

Comment: Where's the close-as-potentially-harmful option?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use `<div>` tags and then just set them to `display:inline` instead of using spans or just naturally styling the link element. Without looking at the example, there feels like a lot of superfluous HTML in there, which never helps. My money is on the `float: right` in the `div#home`, but without handing my facebook profile to you, I can't tell for sure. Do you use anything like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)? it's handy because you can turn CSS rules on and off and see the effect in real time.

Comment: I never asked for access to your Facebook profile. What are you referring to?

Comment: Malphas, I need the home button to be right-aligned in the parent div, which is why I use 'float: right'. Are you suggesting there's a better way to right align that element?

Comment: Malphas, I do have firebug on FF, but the problem only manifests on IE8, so firebug isn't much help.

Comment: Your link to your application, facebook asks for permission for your app to gain access to users' profiles. There are lots of different ways of making things appear in the right place, floats usually cause most headaches in my experience, particularly when you're mixing floating stuff with non-floating stuff. IE is a particular culprit for doing this too.

Comment: So far, with the code you've given, i can't reproduce the problem in IE8. Can you give me the location of the image, so I can see if that has some bearing on the problem? It also may be an issue with the surrounding HTML and CSS.

Comment: I apologize for the Facebook profile issue. I quess I didn't think it would be a problem. I did try to create a link that bypasses Facebook and goes directly to my server. Try this: http://railsacrosseurope-dev.com/index/test

Comment: Nope, that redirects to the Facebook page.

Comment: You could take this to DocType; the people there would probably be more helpful. http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix. I changed the div#home rule to this:

```
  div#home {
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    bottom: 4px;
  }
```